# input type="file" does not work in cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova based app and cannot get the file browser to launch on android (SDK-23) with HTML File tag

```
 <input type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.rdf,.txt,.pdf,.odt" 
                    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)">
```

Nothing happens when I select the link.

Can you please give some suggestion on how to fix this issue

Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

`<input type="file">` will not work in Cordova. You need to use the [File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#cordova-plugin-file).

Comment: Thanks for the  link but how do I get the picker to show the list of file..

Comment: How to use File Plugin? it seems that <input type="file"> and File Plugin are completely different things!