# Open Android camera without java or cordova js

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, cordova, android-camera

Let me explain my architecture - I have a web project in react js, I am using Cordova just as an apk creator by mentioning my website url in the config file. (ie WWW folder of cordova project only contains index.html)

My problem statement is - I am unable to open android camera (file picker works fine).

There is one solution which would work that is to implement camera functionality in java and call it via js.(but i have been limited to not use java).

Is there any alternate solution to this problem?

- **UPDATE**

I tried the plugin inappbrowser (did not work)

I tried crosswalk webview (did not work)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure JS and [Image Capture Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture)

Here are two examples:

- [grab-frame-take-photo](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/grab-frame-take-photo.html)
- [imagecapture](https://simpl.info/imagecapture/)

If you need native camera HTML5 is enough:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Comment: I have been restricted to use the native Android camera, I already achieved it with your approach. Do you have any suggestions wherein it uses the native camera?

Comment: Than you only need HTML5 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />

Comment: I tried it, It does not work in android build, however if I try it directly in browser it works fine.

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476916/input-type-file-does-not-work-in-cordova